Button lock on Canon IXUS 60
I have an Old Canon IXUS 60 digital camera. And suddenly all the buttons stopped reacting except the on button and the one that takes the photo. Chat gpt says that I have accidentally locked the button, and if that’s the case how do I unlock it? And if it’s something else what can I do?

Have you try to pull out the battery for 24 hours and then pull it back and power on the camera?

No i haven’t all though there has been a dead battery in it while it’s been turned off overnight, to charge the other battery

I owned the very similar IXUS 70 for a large number of years and don't recall such a function existing on that camera; similarly I can't find any mention of such a function in the manual on Canon's web site.
Therefore my hypothesis is:

ChatGPT is lying ("hallucinating", whatever you want to call it)
Something more fundamental is wrong with the camera. I would (as suggested in a comment) actually take the battery out completely for 24 hours and see if that helps, but if not you may just have to accept that your 18 year old camera has done pretty well and can now be retired; it's not worth getting it repaired.

